# PowerShell script to process audio streams with ffmpeg results in unexpected conversion

Tags: ffmpeg, video, powershell, conversion

So, I've gone down the rabbit hole trying to do recursive conversions with ffmpeg using powershell.

The script is almost doing what i want it to, but not completely.
In this argument, AC3 is converted to Vorbis and PCM is converted to Opus while DTS is copied.

I want AC3 to be copied and PCM to be converted to pcm_s16be.

My test folder has videos with ac3, dts and pcm

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video (native) -> hevc (hevc_nvenc))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (ac3 (native) -> vorbis (libvorbis))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
```

Any idea of where I went wrong?
This is for music videos by the way

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path converted; 
Get-ChildItem -Path .\* -Include *.VOB,*.mkv -Recurse | ForEach-Object
  { 
  $audioStreams = ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams a -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language:stream=codec_name -of csv=p=0 $_.FullName; $audioArgs = @(); 
  $audioStreams | ForEach-Object 
    { 
    $streamIndex,$streamLang,$codecName = $_.Split(","); 
    if ($streamIndex -ne $null -and $streamIndex -lt 2) 
      { 
      if ($codecName -eq "ac3") 
        { 
        $codec = "copy" 
        } 
      else 
        { 
        $codec = switch ($streamLang) { "dts" { "copy" } "pcm" { "pcm_s16be" } default { "copy" } } 
        }; 
      $audioArgs += "-map","0:a:?$streamIndex","-c:a:$streamIndex",$codec 
      } 
    }; 
  Write-Host "ffmpeg arguments: -fflags +genpts -i $($_.FullName) -vf bwdif,unsharp=lx=3:ly=3:la=0.5 -map 0:v @audioArgs -c:v hevc_nvenc -profile:v main10 -rc:v vbr -cq:v 18 converted\$($_.BaseName).mkv"; ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i $_.FullName -vf bwdif,unsharp=lx=3:ly=3:la=0.5 -map 0:v @audioArgs -c:v hevc_nvenc -profile:v main10 -rc:v vbr -cq:v 18 converted\$($_.BaseName).mkv 
  }
```

Comment: Do you *have* to use PowerShell?

Comment: no, i'm not bound to ps.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles than "Powershell and FFMPEG" that tells nothing about what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Destroy666
Will try to improve if i have another question :)

Comment: For one thing, if you want to write the switch in a single line, you need to put semi-colons between the options: `$codec = switch ($streamLang) { "dts" { "copy" }; "pcm" { "pcm_s16be" }; default { "copy" } }`. Next, you are concatenating an **undefined** variable `$audioArgs`. Not only that, but you should try to not use `+=` to what seems to become an array.